# Using svg or font icon in the ios applications

Tags: ios, iphone, svg, ios7, xamarin.ios

In my iOS application we need to change the color of the icons based on the user configuration. It is one of our important business option.

One of my friend advised me for using .svg or font icon. And shared me this [link](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)

They are creating web applications while I am developing iOS application. Does iOS support this technique too? If yes, how can I use it?

**Edit**

I found [SVGKit](https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit) that is used for the iPhone/iPad apps. Is there any binding library for using it on the monotouch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SVG fonts (paths) are kind of easy to convert into source code. Once you have this it's very simple to render them in different colours, sizes (iphone/ipad) or resolutions (e.g. retina).

That's what I did [here](https://github.com/spouliot/svgpath2code). That's for an older version of FontAwesome, but it could be used as is (or updated to the latest) for your application.

Comment: as I see this is for Mac, I can not open it with xamarin studio and monotouch. My question is about using svg on the ios apps. Is it possible?

Comment: I found this https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit that seem is for using on the iphone/ipad apps. Is there any binding library for using it on the monotouch?

Comment: You did not look far enough. Tere's an iOS demo of the **results** but the convertion from SVG to source code is done on the Mac (or Windows) since it's where the compilation (of the source code) can occur.  https://github.com/spouliot/svgpath2code/tree/master/AwesomeDemo

Answer (score 0):

you can use [FontAwesome+iOS](https://github.com/alexdrone/ios-fontawesome)

all the icons available here: [link](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/)

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to change color of icons, you probably can solve this without svg. Just use tint colors.

Create a template image:

```
let templateImage = UIImage(named: "bla_bla")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
```

Then add it to a button or an image view and set the `tintColor`:

```
button.setImage(templateImage, for: .normal)
button.setImage(templateImage, for: .highlighted)

button.tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

This solution works only for monochromatic icons!

Besides, if you want .svg, you can use `WKWebView`, it's really fast and will not cause overhead if you have limited amount of icons.